# Import data from one Google Sheet to another sorted in a different order

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to import data from one Google Sheet document to another. The data are in different order on each Sheet. I've used IMPORTRANGE, but this keeps it in the order on the first sheet ("Example" below). Instead, I want the data to map to the order on the second sheet ("Copy of Confirmed Vendors Tracking Sheet") using the order of the data in **Column A **(Brewing Co 3, Brewing Co 2, etc.).

A specific example:

- Import data from **Column L **in "Example" Sheet into **Column F** in "Copy of Confirmed Vendors Tracking Sheet" using the sort order of **Column A** in "Copy of Confirmed Vendors Tracking Sheet."

Is this possible?

First sheet (output): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kSmgyn3AM6jHULmOl5RuLpIbYsBJ9B5ecCuakoBj7T8/edit#gid=0

Second sheet (import destination): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bO0cuM91a0jwgiRvoZx98qQXwCT_PsL3tz4JEZ17etA/edit#gid=483217923

I have tried using IMPORTRANGE, but this imports the data in the source order.

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: Try `QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(...), "order by ...")`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the data returned by the IMPORTRANGE formula as a lookup table and use the vendor names in your destination sheet as the search strings for VLOOKUP in an ARRAYFORMULA.

In this way you would retrieve the associated values in the correct order for the destination.

The last row containing a vendor is calculated for both the source and the destination to avoid including unnecessary blank rows in the lookups.

## Example Formula

```
=LET(vendors,A2:A,
   sourceData,QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(   
     "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"&
     "1kSmgyn3AM6jHULmOl5RuLpIbYsBJ9B5ecCuakoBj7T8",
     "Sheet1!A:L"), "WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL"), 
   lastRow,ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(MATCH(2,1/(LEN(vendors)>0)))), 
   ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(
     QUERY(vendors, "LIMIT "& lastRow, 0),
     sourceData, 12, 0))))
```

1. **`vendors`** is in your destination sheet.
2. **`sourceData`** is your IMPORTRANGE formula placed inside a QUERY to remove blank rows.
3. **`lastrow`** calculates the last data row in **`vendors`** to reduce unnecessary lookups.
4. The final ARRAYFORMULA does a VLOOKUP for each value in **`vendors`** and returns the value in column L (12) of the matched row in **`sourceData`**.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am getting a 'formula parse error' when I enter this. What does this mean: ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(MATCH(2,1/(LEN(vendors)>0)))), 
   ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(
     QUERY(vendors, "LIMIT "& lastRow, 0),
     sourceData, 12, 0))))

Comment: I fixed a typo in the sheet name **`Sheet`** instead of **`Sheeet`**